# Where to put custom RichFaces my.skin.properties file?

Tags: jsf, tomcat, richfaces

The docs say put it in META-INF/skins, but RichFaces doesn't find it there, or anywhere else I tried.

I use Tomcat with MyFaces 2 JSF and RichFaces 4 components

**Update**: I posted the Exception that Tomcat throws at http://paste.lisp.org/display/128193

**Update 2**: In response to BalusC's comments below, I established that specifying org.richfaces.SKIN in uppercase also doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [community forums](https://community.jboss.org/thread/162295) notes that the `my.skin.properties` file (note: pluralizing *skin* to *skins*--as in `my.skins.properties`--is incorrect) must be in `WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/skins`.

In NetBeans, for example, this can be accomplished as follows:

1. Switch to the **Files** tab.
2. Create a new directory at the same level as src and web called `resources`.
3. Create a sub-directory in `resources` called `WEB-INF`.
4. Copy `my.skin.properties` into **resources/WEB-INF**.
5. Update `web.xml` to contain:

   ```
   <context-param>
       <param-name>org.richfaces.skin</param-name>
       <param-value>my</param-value>
   </context-param>
   ```

> **Note:** Some places, including the formal documentation, refer to the skin param-name as `org.richfaces.SKIN`, which is incorrect. The param-name must be all lowercase.

Next:

1. Update `build.xml` to contain:

   ```
   <target name="-post-dist">
     <war destfile="${dist.war}" update="true">
       <zipfileset dir="${basedir}/resources/WEB-INF" prefix="WEB-INF/classes" />
     </war>
   </target>
   ```
2. Press <kbd>Shift+F11</kbd> to rebuild the application.

Verify that the archive (e.g., Project.war) contains the following file:

```
\Project.war\WEB-INF.classes\my.skin.properties
```

When deployed, the application should find the properties file.